# Dynamic generation of sheet name from cell content (cell contents from importrange)

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a list of names of the members of my group. Each member has a separate sheet that contains information on that member. When a new person joins the group, I input the name to the master list and duplicate a template so that person will have a separate info sheet. Cell A1 imports (importrange)the member's name. I want automate the tab name change on the member info sheet. This facilitates a single input point for the member's name. I have attempted a script recommended on StackExchange:

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var oldName = sheet.getName();
  var newName = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
  if (newName.toString().length>0 && newName !== oldName) {
    sheet.setName(newName);
  }
}
```

This script does not change the tabname, I think because the name is being imported from another sheet.

Comment: Related: [Dynamic generation of sheet name from cell content](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/84190/88163)

Answer (score 0):

The edit event only occurs when a user directly makes an edit to cells on the spreadsheet. Changes on values due to a recalculation of a formula or made by a script doesn't triggs the onEdit() function.

You should trigger it by other means.