# Auto create new sheet when new data in column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I'm trying to create a new sheet on google sheets whenever column B gets a new value. This sheet will be named the value that created it. . I also want to have a function in the new sheet that contains the value that created the new sheet.

For example, if B3 gets the value "John Doe", a new sheet will be created titles "John Doe" and A1 of that sheet will be the filter function with "John Doe" as the filter.

I tried using macros but they are way over my head. I figured out how to create a new sheet in a script but from there I'm stumped.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. You said "I figured out how to create a new sheet in a script but from there I'm stumped." Don't worry about being stumped - everyone has to start somewhere, and I agree that macros have their uses, but this is not one of them. Would you please edit your question to include your script that creates the new sheet.

Comment: Related: [Dynamic generation of sheet name from cell content](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/84190/196152)

Comment: Related: [Writing a macro to create a new tab and name that tab based on a cell value in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/134850/196152)

Comment: Giovanni, did you resolve your problem or do you still need help?